# MongoDB Event trigger after data inserted into mongoDB Collection

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, jsp, spring-boot

I am very new to MongoDB. I have made a "crude" operation with MongoDB.

I want to work with event functionality in MongoDB which is when data is inserted into MongoDB collection event should occur and **data should be imediately emitted on UI by MongoDB itself.**

Is This Possible in MongoDB?

If Yes then How? and if No then Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tailable cursor` with the option `Bytes.QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA`. Documentation on Mongodb's tailable cursor: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/

> ... After clients insert new additional documents into a capped
>   collection, the tailable cursor will continue to retrieve documents.

When you retrieve documents using an unsatisfied query, an empty cursor will be returned. Then, when you call `cur.hasNext()`, it will wait for data to be present (with a timeout):

```
mongoTemplates.createCollection("model", new CollectionOptions(null, 10, true));
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("value", "val");
DBCursor cur = mongoTemplates.getCollection("model")
            .find(query)
            .addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_TAILABLE)
            .addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA);

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //cur.hasNext will wait for data
        while (cur.hasNext()) {
            DBObject obj = cur.next();
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    };
}.start();
```

- `cursor.hasNext()` will unblock when you insert the following in mongodb: `db.model.insertOne({value: "val"})`

For this to work, the collection has to be created with the option "capped":

- in java: `mongoTemplates.createCollection("model", new CollectionOptions(MAX_SIZE_BYTES, MAX_NB_DOCUMENTS, IS_CAPPED));`
- in mongo client: `db.createCollection( "model", { capped: true, size: 10 } )`

The `Capped Collection` is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/):

> By default, MongoDB will automatically close a cursor when the client
>   has exhausted all results in the cursor. However, for **capped
>   collections** you may use a **Tailable Cursor** that remains open
>   after the client exhausts the results in the initial cursor.